# How do I use MS Charting in a mixed web forms and mvc site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, charts, webforms

I've got a web forms application that uses MS Chart control successfully.  I installed MVC 3 and the charts broke.  The chart url is matching the standard mvc route, so I'm getting a 404 error.  I've tried all sorts of different IgnoreRoute configurations that I've found here on stackoverflow, but none have resolved the issue.

Can anyone tell me why this does not work:  `routes.IgnoreRoute("ChartImg.axd/{*pathInfo}");`

And what the correct solution would be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the [RouteDebugger by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx). It will show you what rule the route is hitting.

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my original question, it is matching the default route.  Why isn't the IgnoreRoute working?

Comment: By the way, since my original post, I have discovered the web.config setting, WebDevServerUseConfigSettings=true.  This forces chart to use the web.config settings (because in development, chart always serves images from memory, not from file). This is relevant, because now I can see that the handler is receiving my request, writing the chart images to the file location, but still giving me a 404.